# The difference between "can be" and "may be"?

Tags: modal-verbs

What is the difference between "can be" and "may be"?

> 1. Analysing reports of investigations **may be** observed...
> 2. Analysing reports of investigations **can be** observed...

Comment: As a general rule, I don't want to close questions about differences between auxiliary verbs as entirely answerable by a dictionary.  They're tricky, and too often there are gotchas waiting to trick learners, even advanced ones.  Even though this particular case is fairly straightforward, I think it should be left open.

Comment: The Q&A is designed so the poor soul in need of Google gets a simple and readable format instead of a cryptic dictionary. This serves that purpose. Why it's on the 'close-pending' list I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Can" simply means that the observation is possible. There is no reason for it to happen, but it is a possibility. In this context, it doesn't give any indication that the observation is likely to happen.

"May" is more direct. It defines a possibility that is more likely to happen, as the observation could be actively made to happen. It can also define something being given permission to happen: that statement is giving 'permission' for the observation to happen, regardless of whether its possible.

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to say is that the use of modal verbs is a complicated subject, since a given modal verb *can* have different uses, and different modal verbs *may* have a similar use.

The following is based on the advise given in ["Science Research Writing for Non-Native Speakers of English"](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Science_Research_Writing_for_Non_native.html?id=nu9LZ1x8l8oC). This book lists the following uses for *can* and *may*:

**CAPABILITY**

> This software **can** distinguish between different languages
>
> Until 18 months a child **cannot** use symbols to represent objects

**POSSIBILITY/OPTIONS**

> A rubber seal **can** be useful for this purpose
>
> A rubber seal **cannot** be useful for this purpose
>
> A rubber seal **may** be useful for this purpose
>
> A rubber seal **may not** be useful for this purpose

**VIRTUAL CERTAINTY**

> It is clear that contamination **cannot** be due to the presence of seawater in the pipe

Answer (score 2):

MMJZ gave you a good answer. I suggest you taking that one. I'll make a complement here.

By and large, "Can" represents a theoretical possiblity while "May" represents a factual possiblity.

Let's say, when you discuss the local weather with your friends,

If your friend says that *it **can** be quite cold there in winter*, what he says is just a general view of what the weather is **usually** like in winter. He is not predicting whether it's cold or warm in winter **that year**.

However, if he says that *it **may** be quite cold there in winter*, He is predicting from past experience that it's likely to be cold in winter **that year**.

Comment: Please supply the complete sentences.  The portions you have supplied do not seem to make sense. Or rather, they seem to set up a five-phase progression.  1) something happens  2) it is investigated 3) reports are made of the investigations 4) the reports are analysed 5) the analyses are "observed" .  Is it really that complicated?

Comment: **By and large, "Can" represents a theoretical possiblity while "May" represents a factual possiblity.** This explanation (if correct) is the most brilliant one that I've ever seen on this subject.